# How to get all stop words from Spacy and don't get any errors? TypeError: argument of type 'module' is not iterable

Tags: python, nlp, data-science, spacy

How to get all stop words from `spacy.lang.en` and don't get any errors?

```
from spacy.lang.en import stop_words as stop_words


def tokenize(sentence):
    sentence = nlp(sentence)
    # lemmatizing
    sentence = [ word.lemma_.lower().strip() if word.lemma_ != "-PRON-" else word.lower_ for word in sentence ]
    # removing stop words
    sentence = [ word for word in sentence if word not in stop_words and word not in punctuations ]        
    return sentence
```

```
tokenize("Hallo ik ben leyla en ") and then i get
```

Then I got the following error and This is the error that I got

```
TypeError: argument of type 'module' is not iterable
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . After that please update and improve your question.

Comment: What modules are you using?

Comment: @statnet22 using the spacy package  i wrote this function to remove, stopwords

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure `stop_words` and `punctuations` be a `list` or `set` and for getting a set of all `stop_words` from `from spacy.lang.en import stop_words` you can use **`stop_words.STOP_WORDS`** or as an alternative solution you can use `nlp.Defaults.stop_words`.

```
import spacy
from string import punctuation
from spacy.lang.en import stop_words


nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

stop_words = stop_words.STOP_WORDS
# print(stop_words)
# as an alternative solution
# stop_words = nlp.Defaults.stop_words


punctuations = list(punctuation)
print(punctuations)
# ['!', '"', '#', '$', '%', '&', "'", '(', ')', '*', '+', '', '', '-', '.', '/', ':', ';', '<', '=', '>', '?', '@', '[', '\\', ']', '^', '_', '`', '{', '|', '}', '~']


def tokenize(sentence):
    sentence = nlp(sentence)
    # lemmatizing
    sentence = [ word.lemma_.lower().strip() if word.lemma_ != "-PRON-" else word.lower_ for word in sentence ]
    # removing stop words
    sentence = [ word for word in sentence if word not in stop_words and word not in punctuations ]        
    return sentence
```

---

```
>>> tokenize("Hallo ik ben leyla en ")
['hallo', 'ik', 'ben', 'leyla', 'en']
```

Comment: @l'mahdi   Thanks a lot but what is the differents between how you set your stopword and how i set my stopwords.